# MySQL last rows ordered view

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-view

I can get 50 last rows from MySQL table and order its:

```
(SELECT * FROM RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY N ASC;
```

I get error when I try to create a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW `new_view` AS
(SELECT * FROM RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY N ASC;
```

How can I create a view with the last 50 rows in ascending order?

P.S.
Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`MySQL_Admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetLast50`()
BEGIN
(SELECT * FROM mkdb.RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY N;
END
```

Works fine.

Comment: Just put the asc order in your subsequent query... `select * from myview order by n` - although why anyone would bother with a view in MySQL is quite frankly beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a select to order by

```
CREATE VIEW `new_view` AS
select * from (SELECT * FROM RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) S ORDER BY N ASC;
```

Comment: Not work. Error: 
==
ERROR 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias
SQL Statement:
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `new_view` AS
select * from (SELECT * FROM RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY N ASC

Answer (score 0):

While creating view, you have to SELECT something FROM **table** or **another query**.

```
CREATE VIEW `new_view` AS
select * from (SELECT * FROM RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY N ASC;
```

And then again you can SELECT something FROM **view**

Comment: Not work. Error: 
==
ERROR 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias
SQL Statement:
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `new_view` AS
select * from (SELECT * FROM RawData ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 50) ORDER BY N ASC